# Give a name to a writeable bitmap

Tags: c#, gridview, bitmap, windows-phone-8.1, filenames

I wonder if there is any way to give a name to a writeableBitmap

I have 3 images in my folder.  To display them in a gridView I convert them to a wrtieableBitmap

```
if (file.Count > 0)
        {
            var images = new List<WriteableBitmap>();
            foreach (StorageFile f in file)
            {
                var name = f.Name;
                Debug.WriteLine(f.Name);

                ImageProperties properties = await f.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
                if (properties.Width > 0)
                {
                    var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)properties.Width, (int)properties.Height);

                    Debug.WriteLine(bitmap.PixelWidth);
                    using (var stream = await f.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        bitmap.SetSource(stream);
                    }
                    images.Add(bitmap);
                    Debug.WriteLine(images.Count);
                }
            }
```

The I add them to the gridView by binding the Data as in AlGridView.DataContext = images;

Now, once I interact with those images and I press a button I need to save the selection...but using an array with numbers [1,2,3]

Before converting them, as you may see above, I had a name (which is 1.png, 2.png, etc) but once they are writeablebitmaps I haven´t found any way to give / get a name out of them

And

```
bitmap.SetVale(Name, f.Name);
```

Does not work, since it says it cannot convert a string into a DependencyProperty

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ha!. I think I have found the solution:

```
properties.Title = name;
var bitmap = new WriteableBitmap((int)properties.Width, (int)properties.Height);
bitmap.SetValue(NameProperty, (string)properties.Title);
```

Thank you all!